# Spring Quartz Blocking Threads

Tags: multithreading, spring, quartz-scheduler, blocking

Currently, I am using spring quartz to fire three different jobs at different times. I am using three different schedulers for each trigger.
This scenario works fine for the first couple of hours but then all quartz threads become blocked. The following is my bean definition:

```
> <!-- TRAFFIC POLLER DECLERATION -->
  >     <!-- job -->
  >     <bean id="TriggerJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  >         <property name="targetObject" ref="TriggerClass" />
  >         <property name="targetMethod" value="trigger" />
  >     </bean>
  >     
  >     <!-- trigger -->
  >     <bean id="trigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
  >         <property name="jobDetail" ref="TriggerJob" />
  >         <property name="cronExpression" value="${trigger.cron}" />  
  >     </bean>
  >     
  >     <!-- SCHEDULER -->
  >     <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
  >         <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
  >         <property name="triggers">
  >             <list>
  >                 <ref bean="trigger1" />
  >             </list>
  >         </property>
  >     </bean>
```

The following is the stack trace from my jconsole of the blocked threads:

```
Name: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-5
State: BLOCKED on java.lang.Object@131b502 owned by: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-6
Total blocked: 20  Total waited: 101,919

Stack trace: 
com.ecs.Trigger.TriggerClass trigger(TriggerClass.java:89)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Anyone has got any idea why I am having this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that on job (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-5) is synchronizing with another one org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#1_Worker-6 and is waiting for this one for releasing a resource. 
Do you have some wait()/notify() instructions in your jobs? 
or do you sinchronize the same job on some variable and you did not set  in your TriggerJob?
You did not set concurrent=false so it may be that two instances on the same job are running and one is waiting for the same job executed in another thread.

Comment: The methods being called are synchronized, there are no shared variables or notify/wait. The methods are completely indepenendent of each other.

Comment: are these method called from other threads other than the job ones?